# get index of string in Array and delete in an other Array the strings at these indexes

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexof

I have two arrays :

```
String[] dishes = {"Dish1", "Dish2", "Dish3", "Dish4", "Dish5", "Dish6"};
String[] dishCategory = {"daily Dish", "daily Dish", "daily Dish", "side Dish", "side Dish", "Dish special"};
```

As result I want two Arrays: one with the daily dishes and the dish special in it, and the other one only with the side dishes.

That's why I tried to get the "side Dish" index of the dishCategory to delete these Strings of my dishes Array. But I even couldn't work out a function to get all the "side dish" indexes.

Does anyone know a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this to create 2 new arrays.

```
List<String> dailyAndSpecialList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> sideList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < dishCategory.length; i++) {
  if (dishCategory[i].equals("side Dish")) {
    sideList.add(dishes[i]);
  } else {
    dailyAndSpecialList.add(dishes[i]);
  }
}
String[] sideArray = sideList.toArray(new String[sideList.size()]);
String[] dailyAndSpecialArray = dailyAndSpecialList.toArray(new String[dailyAndSpecialList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the dishCategory array and compare the element of array with your "side dish" and store the matching index in other Arraylist and later on using these index , you can remove or do whatever you want to do.

sample code  :-

```
ArrayList<Integer> sideDishIdx = new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0;
        for(String s : dishCategory){
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("side Dish"))
                sideDishIdx.add(i);
            i++;

        }
        for(Integer idx : sideDishIdx){
            System.out.println("idx "+idx);
        }
```